# Obtaining IP Address when Using NPS/RADIUS with existing lease from Windows DHCP

Tags: active-directory, vlan, dhcp-server, access-point, nps

Problem: I have DHCP clients on a Windows AD network contoso.local, that often can't get an IP address after successfully authenticating over the RADIUS/NPS Server. I found that if the device has an existing lease from another VLAN or Subnet than what it's trying to obtain, it doesn't get an IP address. Sometimes it will instead give an IP address from the wired network. Does Windows DHCP provide a way around this? I would assume so, but am puzzled at where to find this?

Setup:
3 networks
WIRED NETWORK - 192.168.1.0/24
WIRELESS NETWORK - 192.168.2.0/24
INFRASTRUCTURE NETWORK (where management interfaces are at) - 192.168.3.0/24

The AP is part of the infrastructure network with native VLAN set for it's network for the device. It is allowing the VLAN of the WIRELESS NETWORK only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be use of Super Scopes on the Windows DHCP server.

After applying the changes, clients switching between subnets were able to receive leases each time.